# can't get view to dismiss on didExitRegion in swift

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

When a user exits my defined geofence. All of the other code within the function fires as expected but the view does not dismiss. Any suggestions?

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setBool(false, forKey: self.userCheckInKey)
    ProgressHUD.showError("You are no longer checked-in")
    //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToMainScreen", sender: self)

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

also as a note I am using JSQMessages library and this view is a JSQMessagesView

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class LocalMessagesViewController: JSQMessagesViewController, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

UPDATED FUNC:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setBool(false, forKey: self.userCheckInKey)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            ProgressHUD.showError("You are no longer checked-in")
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

Comment: if didExitRegion method is called on other thread than main this can be the problem. So call self.dismissViewControllerAnimated on main thread, it's the only thread that deals with UI

Comment: any suggestions on how to ensure the dismiss self.dismissViewControllerAnimated is only executed when the user leaves the geofence?

Comment: Call self.dismissViewControllerAnimated  on main thread

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            })

Comment: ok I see. Great Ill give that a try!

Comment: I updated my code but still no luck.